# Python: when lambda is used to iterate, notation does not make sense

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

Here is some code from Python Cookbook.

```
portfolio = [
       {'name': 'IBM', 'shares': 100, 'price': 91.1},
       {'name': 'AAPL', 'shares': 50, 'price': 543.22},
       {'name': 'FB', 'shares': 200, 'price': 21.09},
       {'name': 'HPQ', 'shares': 35, 'price': 31.75},
       {'name': 'YHOO', 'shares': 45, 'price': 16.35},
       {'name': 'ACME', 'shares': 75, 'price': 115.65}
]

    cheap = heapq.nsmallest(3, portfolio, key=lambda s: s['price'])
```

How is the "s['price']" expression calculated?  How "s" is referring to `portfolio`?

I iterate through the dictionary and can get all prices one by one by using `portfolio[loop index]['price']` viz. portfolio[0]['price']....and so on.  So `nsmallest` can find the 3 smallest prices.

Used the following to confirm it.

```
cheap = heapq.nsmallest(3, portfolio, key=lambda s: f's {s}')
```

Omitting the price. I got three records and don't know how smallest was determined.

So, I think `s['price']` is acting like `portfolio[s]['price']` where s is the index of record.

Just can't figure out how s gets bound to portfolio and why key `lambda s: [s]['price']` is error.

Comment: As stated in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest), it works as the `key` argument in [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).

Comment: TL;DR: `s` will be _one of the items_ of `portfolio`. `nsmallest` will call the `lambda`, passing it _one of the items_ as necessary.

Comment: `[s]` is a list with one item, it does not have a `'price'` as a dictionary key, so `[s]['price']` is an error

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  One issue is clear.  Its the "key" that associates the "s" with the iterable "portfolio" while using nsmallest.  So, I am to assume that when used in this way, the argument in lambda will be a kind of loop counter from 0 to the length of iterable and and produce the same result as portfolio[0]['price'] but for all records in the portfolio i.e compile a list of price values for nsmallest to do its magic.  Correct?

Comment: Again: `s` will be _one of the items_ of `portfolio`. `nsmallest` will call the `lambda`, passing it _one of the items_ as necessary. — Have you read the duplicate above?